# Can someone explain to me the thought process behind this proof for a linear equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

I'm having a **slight** uncertainty towards what is going on in this proof. From my understanding, this is what I believe is happening:

- The '3' denominator is being taken out
- Accomplished by multiplying everything by 3

HOWEVER,

I notice there is a 3 added in the fraction, making it 3(2m - 4) / 3. I do not understand this part, since a 3 is being added which does nothing as the 2m - 4 remains the same through out. Can someone explain why there is a 3 infront of 2m - 4, when it is the denominator, I really don't know how to word my question any better , sorry. I understand WHY 'm' and 6 are multiplied by 3, but not the numerator which had a 3 added in front (which did nothing).

Answer (score 2):

The proof just multiplied **everything** by $3$ to have an equation without any fraction.

You can see the following :
$$3\times \frac{2m-4}{3}=\frac{3(2m-4)}{3}.$$

The proof did as
$$m+\frac{2m-4}{3}=6$$
$$\Rightarrow 3\times m+3\times \frac{2m-4}{3}=3\times 6$$
$$\Rightarrow 3\times m+\frac{3(2m-4)}{3}=3\times 6$$
$$\Rightarrow 3m+(2m-4)=18.$$

At the last step you'll see that you can calculate as 
$$\frac{3(2m-4)}{3}=2m-4.$$